# installing vimtex?

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-vimtex

I am trying to install [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), and I am not how to do that. What plugin manager should I use?

How do I combine it with "vim-surround"? "snipmate"?

I went through the [readme](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/README.md) file, but could not really understand how vimtex could be used with other plugin managers. I could not install `vim-plug`

Comment: My favorite plugin manager is pathogen.
https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen

Comment: https://github.com/lervag/vimtex#installation

Comment: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#installation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install with [vim-pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), this should work (taken directly from the readme, I just swapped vim-sensible with vimtex):

> Now any plugins you wish to install can be extracted to a subdirectory under ~/.vim/bundle, and they will be added to the 'runtimepath'. Observe:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/lervag/vimtex.git
```

> Now vimtex is installed. If you really want to get crazy, you could set it up as a submodule in whatever repository you keep your dot files in. I don't like to get crazy.

I further suggest you read the full readme of vim-pathogen, as well as other plugin managers that might be of interested, e.g.:

- [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)
- [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)
- [neobundle](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim)

---

Regarding how to combine vimtex with other plugins: I don't understand the question. In principle, it should just work.